Generalizations of Michael theorem
In [1] Michael proved the following:
Theorem. Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be continuous, closed, and onto, where $X$ is $T_1$. If $y \in Y$ is a q-point, then every continuous, real-valued function on $X$ is bounded on $\partial{f^{-1}(y)}$.
Are there any generalizations or refinements of this theorem?
[1] Michael, E. (1964). A note on closed maps and compact sets. Israel Journal of Mathematics, 2, 173-176.

There is an extension by N. Dykes [1]:

If $f$ is a continuous, closed map of a topologically complete space
$X$ onto a q-space $Y$, then $\partial{f^{-1}(y)}$ is compact for each
$y\in Y$.

[1] N. Dykes, Mappings and real compact spaces (1969).

Ever so slightly more generally, in the statement of Dyke's theorem you can replace Dieudonné completeness with strong isocompactness. Thus Dyke's statement holds when $X$ is an isocompact $T_4$ space (and hence, for example, if $X$ is submetacompact $T_4$).
